How can I create a column, a kind of rank, that changes based on several columns in oracle sql, as in the example?
This is my table ordered by code and date_time:



date
code
date_time
user_id
operation




20240301
5600
01/03/2024 4:14:16
1
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 6:13:11
2
OP2


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 8:35:37
3
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 8:53:20
4
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 9:28:40
5
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 9:33:18
6
OP3


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 9:33:28
6
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:16:09
7
OP4


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:16:12
7
OP5


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:16:43
7
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:18:06
8
OP2


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:25:25
11
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:38:41
12
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:47:07
9
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:47:58
9
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 11:08:32
10
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 11:35:37
7
OP1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 11:36:37
7
OP1



My new table and result I'd like is:



date
code
date_time
user_id
operation
rank




20240301
5600
01/03/2024 4:14:16
1
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 6:13:11
2
OP2
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 8:35:37
3
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 8:53:20
4
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 9:28:40
5
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 9:33:18
6
OP3
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 9:33:28
6
OP1
2


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:16:09
7
OP4
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:16:12
7
OP5
2


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:16:43
7
OP1
3


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:18:06
8
OP2
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:25:25
11
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:38:41
12
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:47:07
9
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 10:47:58
9
OP1
2


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 11:08:32
10
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 11:35:37
7
OP1
1


20240301
5600
01/03/2024 11:36:37
7
OP1
2



Until user_id change put 1, when it doesn't change, meaning has more date_time, put 1 2 3 etc as much date_time it has. I can't reach that using dense_rank, row_number etc.. The solution will be fine in oracle sql or python as well. Thank you.
Te problem is that the order has to be as code and data_time and a block is where the user_id is not changing; when it changes so is a new block. Using partition is not working.
I tried:
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date_time,user_id) AS RANK_NUM
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY code  ORDER BY date_time,user_id) AS D_RANK_NUM
but it doesn't work properly.

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT "date", code, date_time, user_id, operation, rank
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY "date", code
         ORDER BY date_time
         MEASURES
           COUNT(user_id) AS rank
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( start_user same_user* )
         DEFINE same_user AS user_id = start_user.user_id
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name ("date", code, date_time, user_id, operation) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '04:14:16' HOUR TO SECOND,  1, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '06:13:11' HOUR TO SECOND,  2, 'OP2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '08:35:37' HOUR TO SECOND,  3, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '08:53:20' HOUR TO SECOND,  4, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '09:28:40' HOUR TO SECOND,  5, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '09:33:18' HOUR TO SECOND,  6, 'OP3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '09:33:28' HOUR TO SECOND,  6, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:16:09' HOUR TO SECOND,  7, 'OP4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:16:12' HOUR TO SECOND,  7, 'OP5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:16:43' HOUR TO SECOND,  7, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:18:06' HOUR TO SECOND,  8, 'OP2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:25:25' HOUR TO SECOND, 11, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:38:41' HOUR TO SECOND, 12, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:47:07' HOUR TO SECOND,  9, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '10:47:58' HOUR TO SECOND,  9, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '11:08:32' HOUR TO SECOND, 10, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '11:35:37' HOUR TO SECOND,  7, 'OP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-03-01', 5600, DATE '2024-03-01' + INTERVAL '11:36:37' HOUR TO SECOND,  7, 'OP1' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



date
CODE
DATE_TIME
USER_ID
OPERATION
RANK




2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 04:14:16
1
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 06:13:11
2
OP2
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 08:35:37
3
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 08:53:20
4
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 09:28:40
5
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 09:33:18
6
OP3
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 09:33:28
6
OP1
2


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:16:09
7
OP4
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:16:12
7
OP5
2


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:16:43
7
OP1
3


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:18:06
8
OP2
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:25:25
11
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:38:41
12
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:47:07
9
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 10:47:58
9
OP1
2


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 11:08:32
10
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 11:35:37
7
OP1
1


2024-03-01 00:00:00
5600
2024-03-01 11:36:37
7
OP1
2



fiddle

Thank you so much. Very interesting this code. If I would have, instead of 1 when user_id changes, have the same number for the same user_id? So the result should be like: [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9,10,11,11,etc]?
